# Case insensitive regex in Bash

Tags: regex, bash, case-insensitive

I want to know which method is better to check if a var (input by user on keyboard) matches with a regex in a case insensitive way. I know there are some different possibilities. Example: I want a regex matching an empty value and all of this list: `Y`, `N`, `y`, `n`, `Yes`, `No`, `YES`, `NO`

I searched looking different methods. Not sure if could be another better. I'll put a couple of them working for me.

- First one is a little "tricky" setting all to uppercase for the comparison:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  yesno="null" #any different value for initialization is valid
  while [[ ! ${yesno^^} =~ ^[YN]$|^YES$|^NO$|^$ ]]; do
      read -r yesno
  done
  ```
- Second one is using `shopt -s nocasematch`. But not sure if after doing that it can be reverted because I don't want to set this for all the script.

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  yesno="null" #any different value for initialization is valid
  shopt -s nocasematch
  while [[ ! ${yesno} =~ ^[yn]$|^yes$|^no$|^$ ]]; do
      read -r yesno
  done
  ```

Can these regex get improved in any way?
Is there a better (more elegant) method?
On second method, is there a way to revert that setting?

Comment: `declare -l yesno;  yesno="YES"; echo "$yesno"`?

Comment: To revert `shopt -s nocasematch`: `shopt -u nocasematch`. See: `help shopt`

Comment: Since you asked about the regex, you don't need to repeat the line anchors or the Y/N in Yes/No.  This works: `[[ ! ${yesno^^} =~ ^(Y(ES)?|NO?)$ ]]` and is probably more efficient.  It might be just me, but I find `unset yesno` more clear in your example than setting it to a value that forces an initial false condition (`yesno="null"`), especially since the condition is negated (while NOT true).  But that's probably more a matter of style than good practice.

Comment: BTW since `^$` is not Y/N/YES/NO it's not necessary to specify it.  If you had a situation where null value was a valid response, you could use the zero-or-one quantifier `?` around the outer parens, e.g.: `[[ ${respons,,} =~ ^(bye|quit|exit)?$ ]] && exit 0`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`shopt` is good approach as you are able to retain originally entered value in variable `yesno`.

You can just refactor your regex a bit:

```
#!/bin/bash

yesno="null"

# set nocasematch option
shopt -s nocasematch

while [[ ! ${yesno} =~ ^([yn]|yes|no)?$ ]]; do
    read -r -p "Enter a yes/no value: " yesno
done

# unset nocasematch option
shopt -u nocasematch

# examine your variable
declare -p yesno
```

Answer (score 43):

You can first convert the string into lowercase and check it. Then you don't need to touch `nocasematch` at all.  The content of the variable is left unmodified as well.

```bash
#
# NOTE: This requires Bash 4.0+ (bash 4.0 was released on 2009-02-20)
#
# use the ${var,,} syntax to convert to lowercase
#
while [[ ! ${yesno,,} =~ ^(y|n|yes|no)$ ]]; do
    read -r -p "yes/no? " yesno
done
```

Comment: This looks more elegant than the `shopt` way.

Comment: You should probably add that this is not posix compliant and requires bash >= 4.0.0

Comment: You may need word boundary and any character checks to get this to work if you need to check within multi-word user input. I was struggling for ages because it would give false results for things like `ye s`. Something like this maybe needed. `^.*\b(y|n|yes|no)\b.*$`

Answer (score 4):

The following variant with parenthesis has the advantage of leaving the case sensitivity attribute of the current shell intact by introducing temporary shell context:

```
if ( 
  shopt -s nocasematch; 
  [[ "${yesno}" =~ ^[yn]$|^yes$|^no$|^$ ]]
  ); then
  echo "Yes"
else
  echo "No"
fi
```

Comment: This is the best, if you want it to be temporary!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use the tr (translate) command as it is one of the easiest to use on the command line or within a script.

```
yesno=$(echo $yesno | tr [:upper:] [:lower:])
while [[ ! $yesno =~ ^(y|n|yes|no)$ ]]; do
    read -r -p "yes/no? " yesno
done
```

Answer (score -2):

I like to use `grep` to pattern match instead of Bash. I find it easier to work with, and it should work in other shells other than Bash.
You echo your value into `grep`, apply the regular expression using `grep -E`, then use `wc -l` to count how many lines result. More than zero lines, that's a match.
The `-i` in grep is the flag for case insensitivity.

```
yesno="zzzzzNozzz" #read your value into this variable
if [[ $(echo $yesno | grep -i -E -- "(yes)|(no)|(y)|(n)" | wc -l ) -gt 0 ]]; then
    echo "good!"
else
    echo "bad!"
fi
```

Comment: use `grep -q` instead of piping `grep` into `wc` and comparing the number of lines