# Why Regex doesn't work in bash/ksh while it works fine in command line

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, ksh

I want to exclude any files ending with '.ses' or files with no extension using the following regex pattern. It works fine in command line but not in a shell (bash/ksh).

Regex pattern: `"\.(?!ses\$)([^.]+\$)"`

File name examples:

```
"/test/path/test file with spaces.__1" (expected true)
"/test/path/test file with spaces.ses" (expected false)
"/test/path/test file with spaces" (expected false)
"/test/path/test file with spaces.txt" (expected true)
```

```
FILE_NAME="/test/path/test file with spaces.__1"

PATTERN_STR="\.(?!ses\$)([^.]+\$)"

if [[ "${FILE_NAME}" =~ ${PATTERN_STR} ]]; then

        Match_Result="true"
else

        Match_Result="false"

fi

echo $Match_Result
```

it returns "true" but "false" in the shell. Anyone knows why?

Comment: Which shell are you using?  Is your script and your cli using the same shell?

Comment: I tested your script in my shell and I got an error for using double quotes. The problem is the "!" sign in your string, this must be in single quotes. 
Try changing PATTERN_STR="\\\.(?!ses\$)([^.]+\$)" to PATTERN_STR='\\\.(?!ses\$)([^.]+\$)'.  What I did was change the double quotes " " to single quotes ' '.

Comment: `(?!...)` is PCRE. Bash implements "extended regular expressions" like grep -E. What was you "command line" command you were using?

Comment: @Gill : I don't know what kind of regexp is accepted by ksh, but it does not look like a meaningful bash regexp. Can you demonstrate that it would work inside your script? For instance, in your question I don't see a complete script, nor do I see how you have invoked the script.

Comment: The correct regex would look like this: `[[ "${FILE_NAME##*/}" =~ \.ses$|^[^.]+$ ]] && exclude=yes`. You need to strip any leading path. But I would generally use a case statement, like Allan's answer. It's a lot clearer.

Comment: Thanks everyone. ${PATTERN_STR} is passed as a parameter so it's a bit inflexible. I like Allan's answer if the case statement can be constructed using input parameters maybe using eval?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reverse your logic and fail all strings that contain `.ses` at the end or do not contain a dot after the last `/`.

Then, you can use [this script](https://ideone.com/UIfzgI):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
declare -a arr=("/test/path/test file with spaces.__1"
"/test/path/test file with spaces.ses"
"/test/path/test file with spaces"
"/test/path/test file with spaces.txt")
# true false false true
PATTERN_STR='(/[^/.]+|\.ses)$'
for FILE_NAME in "${arr[@]}"; do
  if [[ "$FILE_NAME" =~ $PATTERN_STR ]]; then
    Match_Result="false"
  else
    Match_Result="true"
  fi
  echo $Match_Result
done;
```

Output:

```
true
false
false
true
```

*Details*:

- `(` - start of a capturing group:

  - `/[^/.]+` - `/` and then one or more chars other than `/` and `.`
- `|` - or

  - `\.ses` - `.ses`
- `)` - end of grouping
- `$` - end of a string.

A case insensitive version is enabled with `shopt -s nocasematch`/`shopt -u nocasematch` (see [Case insensitive regex in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44106842/3832970)).

Comment: Thank you Wiktor, it solved my problem! Just a question though, is it hard to get it working without reversing?

Comment: Good job including test data.  Suggest removing the ! and swapping the two branches of the if statement.

Comment: @Gill It is hard to do with a single POSIX ERE regex though it is possible. It might look like `/[^/.]+\.([^/s][^/][^/]|[^/][^/e][^/]|[^/][^/][^/s]|.{1,2}|.{4,})$`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ex2yo9/2).

Comment: Ahh, then it's no brainer, thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

I would just use a case statement with suitable globs:

```
case "${FILE_NAME##*/}" in
*.ses)
    Match_Result=false
    ;;
*.*)
    Match_Result=true
    ;;    
*)
    Match_Result=false
    ;;
esac
```

Consider using an array instead of doing whitespace gymnastics.

Comment: @JohnKugelman fixed with a hack.

Comment: Good answer, but you should strip any leading path. `FILE_NAME` was a full path, and OP is interested in file names only. `${FILE_NAME##*/}` or `$(basename "$FILE_NAME")`

Comment: @dan updated as suggested.

Comment: Thanks @AllanWind for alternative solution.  Is it possible to construct case statements using input parameters like using eval?

Comment: Yes, both case word and the pattern are pattern expanded.  See also `shopt extglob` which enables `!(pattern-list)` to matches anything except one of the given patterns.